# memory usage with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is the memory consumed by a process spawned by a `multiprocessing.Process` going to be released once the process is joined?

The scenario I have in mind is roughly like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time
import os

def main():
  tasks = Queue()  
  for task in [1, 18, 1, 2, 5, 2]:
    tasks.put(task)

  num_proc = 3           # this many workers @ each point in time
  procs = []
  for j in range(num_proc):
     p = Process(target = run_q, args = (tasks,))  
     procs.append(p)
     p.start()

  # joines a worker once he's done
  while procs:
    for p in procs:
        if not p.is_alive():
            p.join()        # what happens to the memory allocated by run()?  
            procs.remove(p)
            print p, len(procs)
    time.sleep(1)  

def run_q(task_q):
    while not task_q.empty():  # while's stuff to do, keep working
        task = task_q.get()
        run(task)

def run(x):       # do real work, allocates memory
    print x, os.getpid()
    time.sleep(3*x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

In real code, the length of `tasks` is much larger then the number of CPU cores, each `task` is lightweight, different tasks take vastly different amount of CPU time (minutes to days) and vastly different amount of memory (from peanuts to a couple of GBs). All this memory is local to a `run`, and there's no need to share it --- so the question is if it's released once a `run` returns, and/or once a process is joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory consumed by a process is released when the process terminates. In your example, this happens when run_q() returns.